# FileNotFoundError when trying to use os.rename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to write some code which will rename some files in a folder - essentially, they're listed as `xxx_(a).bmp` whereas they need to be `xxx_a.bmp`, where `a` runs from 1 to 2000.

I've used the inbuilt `os.rename` function to essentially swap them inside of a loop to get the right numbers, but this gives me `FileNotFoundError [WinError2] the system cannot find the file specified Z:/AAA/BBB/xxx_(1).bmp' -> 'Z:/AAA/BBB/xxx_1.bmp'`.

I've included the code I've written below if anyone could point me in the right direction. I've checked that I'm working in the right directory and it gives me the directory I'm expecting so I'm not sure why it can't find the files.

```
import os
n = 2000

folder = r"Z:/AAA/BBB/"
os.chdir(folder)

saved_path = os.getcwd()
print("CWD is" + saved_path)

for i in range(1,n):
    old_file = os.path.join(folder, "xxx_(" + str(i) + ").bmp")
    new_file = os.path.join(folder, "xxx_" +str(i)+ ".bmp")
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
print('renamed files')
```

Comment: Are you sure the filename structure is correct? On newer Windows OSs, the default naming for duplicate files is `xxx (1).bmp` not `xxx_(1).bmp`. Space, not underscore.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `os.rename` doesn't create a new directory if the new name is a filename in a directory that does not currently exist.

In order to create the directory first, you can do the following in Python3:

```
os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)
```

In this case dirname can contain created or not-yet-created subdirectories.

As an alternative, one may [use `os.renames`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.renames), which handles new and intermediate directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating files inside the directory and processing the files that meet your criteria.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re

folder = Path("Z:/AAA/BBB/")
for f in folder.iterdir():
    if '(' in f.name:
        new_name = f.stem.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
        # using regex
        # new_name = re.sub('\(([^)]+)\)', r'\1', f.stem)

        extension = f.suffix
        new_path = f.with_name(new_name + extension) 
        f.rename(new_path)
```